What mistake did I make in finding the area bounded by $f(x) = \frac{2}{x}$ and $ g(x)=x-1$ for $1 \le x \le 3$?
Find the area between two graphs, $f(x) = \frac{2}{x}$ and $ g(x)=x-1$ on the interval $1 \le x \le 3$.

Integrals:
$$\text{Area} = \int_{1}^{3} \left(g(x) - f(x)\right) \mathrm dx = \int_{1}^{3} (x-1) \mathrm dx - \int_{1}^{3}\left(\frac{2}{x}\right) \mathrm dx$$
$$= \left[\frac{x^2}{2} - x\right]_{1}^{3} - \left[ 2\ln{x}\right]_{1}^{3}$$
Applying:
$$\text{Area} =\left(\left(\frac{\color{blue}{3}^2}{2} - \color{blue}{3}\right) - \left(\frac{(\color{blue}{1})^2}{2} - \color{blue}{1})\right)\right) - \left(2\ln{\color{red}{3}} - 2\ln{\color{red}{2}}\right)$$
I cannot find the solution, for some reason, according to the back of the book the correct solution is: $$\color{red}{4\ln{2} - 2\ln{3}+1} \approx 1.58$$

You need to subtract in one direction on $[1,2]$ and in the other on $[2,3]$ because $g$ is higher in the first interval and $f$ is higher on the second.

@RossMillikan So, $g(x) - f(x) for \left[1, 2\right]$ and $f(x) - g(x) for \left[2, 3\right]$. Right?

It is the opposite. You want higher function - lower function (There is a typo in the previous comment)

@eti902 Then $G()$ is higher, based on graphing.

corrected $Area = \int_{1}^{3} |g(x) - f(x)| , dx$

@WillJagy Thanks for confirmation .

The area you are looking for is the two roughly triangular regions in the diagram.  $g(x)-f(x)$ is the signed distance between the two curves.  You want the positive distance, so need to use $f(x)-g(x)$ on the interval $[1,2]$ and $g(x)-f(x)$ on the interval $[2,3]$ (my comment had it backwards).  So we have
$$\int_1^2 \frac 2x-(x-1) dx + \int_2^3 (x-1)- \frac 2x dx\\
=[2 \ln x]_1^2-[\frac {x^2}2-x]_1^2+[\frac {x^2}2-x]_2^3-[2 \ln x]_2^3\\
=2 \ln 2-0-0-\frac 12+\frac 52-1-2 \ln 3 + 2 \ln 2\\
=4 \ln 2 - 2 \ln 3 +1$$

Your mistake stems from the fact that you failed to notice $g(x)-f(x)$ is negative from $x=1$ to $x=2$(where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ intersect) whereas area must be positive. This means that $\displaystyle \int_1^2g(x)-f(x)\mathrm dx$ will be negative and thus give the negative of the area bounded between $f(x)$, $g(x)$, $x=1$ and $x=2$.
You can reason this by considering $2$ infinitesimal rectangular strips $A$(in $\color{green}{\text{green}}$) and $B$(in $\color{orange}{\text{orange}}$) between the lines $x=x_1$ and $x=x_1+\mathrm dx_1$ of heights $f(x_1)$ and $g(x_1)$ respectively where $x_1\in[1,2)$. Then, the area bounded by $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and these lines will be the difference of the areas of strips $A$ and $B$, i.e., $f(x_1)\mathrm dx_1-g(x_1)\mathrm dx_1$ as $f(x)>g(x)\forall x\in[1,2)$.

But for $x\in(2,3]$, $g(x)>f(x)$, so this situation is reversed; i.e., the area of the infinitesimal rectangular strip bounded by $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and the lines $x=x_1$, $x=x_1+\mathrm dx_1$, $x_1\in[2,3)$ is given by $g(x_1)\mathrm dx_1-f(x_1)\mathrm dx_1$.

(The images are just for reference, the so-called rectangles have a non-horizontal side lying on $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ because their width is small but finite so that it is convenient to depict them. As the width of the $\color{green}{\text{green}}$ and the $\color{orange}{\text{orange}}$ shapes is set to $0$, the non-horizontal side becomes closer and closer to being horizontal, so they can be approximated as rectangles.)
Hence, for computing the area bounded by the curves and the lines $x=1$, $x=2$, you should compute the integral $\displaystyle \int_1^2\frac2x-x+1\mathrm dx$ and the same for $x=2$, $x=3$ will be $\displaystyle \int_2^3x-1-\frac2x\mathrm dx$. I am sure you can do the rest.
P.S. Generalizing by the same argument as above, the area bounded by the curves $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and the ordinates $x=a$, $x=b$ is given by $\boxed{\displaystyle\int_a^b\left|f(x)-g(x)\right|\mathrm dx}$.

The straight line and hyperbola cross at $(x,y)=(2,1) $
Required positive area =
$$ \int (y_{ ~upper curve~}-y_{ ~lower curve~~}) ~dx $$
$$= \int_1^2(2/x -x+1) dx  +\int_2^3 -(2/x -x+1) dx $$
$$=|2 \log x -x^2/2 +x|_1^2-|2 \log x -x^2/2 +x|_2^3$$
$$=|2 \log x -x^2/2 +x|_1^2+|2 \log x -x^2/2 +x|_3^2$$
Collecting log parts
$$ 4 \log 2 -2 \log 3 $$
Collecting non-log fractions
$$[ -2^2/2 +2) - (-1/2+1)]+  [(-2^2/2+2) - (-3^2/2+3)]$$
$$\text{that simplifies to 1.} $$
